# Inaccurate prediction in MLKit custom model

Tags: android, kotlin, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

Trying to use a retrained MobileNet model to predict dog breeds, but when using the model through Firebase MLKit, it is unable to correctly predict the dog breed. The desktop model and the `tflite` model are both able to correctly predict the breed, but using the same image [of a pug](https://www.petplan.co.uk/images/breed-info/pug/common-health-conditions-carousel-m7a7729-cutout.webp), the desktop model and the `tflite` model (on desktop) are 87.8% confident that it is a pug; whereas on MLKit, the confidence is 1.47x10-2% confident.

I'm suspecting the issue is in my preprocessing of the image in the app code. [The docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models) show how to scale the pixels in the range -1.0, 1.0; which according to the code for the keras image preprocessing function is what is required.

Here is my `infer(iStream)` function where I think the error may lie. Any help is greatly appreciated, this is driving me crazy.

```
private fun infer(iStream: InputStream?) {
    Log.d("ML_TAG", "infer")
    val bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream), 224, 224, true)
    i.setImageBitmap(bmp)
    val bNum = 0
    val input = Array(1) { Array(224) { Array(224) { FloatArray(3) } } }
    for (x in 0..223) {
        for (y in 0..223) {
            val px = bmp.getPixel(x, y)
            input[bNum][x][y][0] = (Color.red(px) - 127) / 255.0f
            input[bNum][x][y][1] = (Color.green(px) - 127) / 255.0f
            input[bNum][x][y][2] = (Color.blue(px) - 127) / 255.0f
        }
    }

    val inputs = FirebaseModelInputs.Builder()
        .add(input)
        .build()

    interpreter.run(inputs, ioOpts).addOnSuccessListener { res ->
        val o = res.getOutput<kotlin.Array<FloatArray>>(0)
        val prob = o[0]

        val r = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(assets.open("retrained_labels.txt")))
        val arrToSort = arrayListOf<Pair<String, Float>>()
        val rArr = r.readLines()
        for (i in prob.indices) {
            val p = Pair(rArr[i], prob[i])
            arrToSort.add(p)
        }
        val sortedList = arrToSort.sortedWith(compareByDescending {it.second})
        val topFive = sortedList.slice(0..4)
        arrToSort.forEach {
            if (it.first == "pug") {
                Log.i("ML_TAG", "Pug: ${it.second}")
            }
        }
        sortedList.forEach {
            if(it.first == "pug") {
                Log.i("ML_TAG", "Pug: ${it.second}")
            }
        }
        topFive.forEach {
            Log.i("ML_TAG", "${it.first}: ${it.second}")
        }
    }
        .addOnFailureListener { res ->
            Log.e("ML_TAG", res.message)
        }
}
```

Comment: What format does your model take inputs in? The pre-processing steps depend on whether its int8/uint8 or float.

Comment: @SachinJoglekar float32

Answer (score 0):

I think `(Color.red(px) - 127) / 255.0f` scales to [-0.5, 0.5]. Does `(Color.red(px) - 127) / 128.0f` produce better results?